# CASE WHEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case-when

I have a set of one to one mappings A -> apple, B-> Banana and like that.. My table has a column with values as A,B,C..

Now I'm trying to use a select statement which will give me the direct result

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you provide the table Schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.job, T1.pid, T2.T2MAX, T1.message, T1.duration, T1.T1SUM ,'message' As message ,
CASE WHEN  T1.T1SUM = 0 THEN 'yellow' WHEN  T1.T1SUM > 0 THEN 'green'   ELSE NULL END  AS color  
       FROM(SELECT monitor.statcatcher.job,monitor.statcatcher.pid, MIN(monitor.statcatcher.moment)AS T1MIN, monitor.statcatcher.message,monitor.statcatcher.duration,
     SUM(Coalesce(monitor.flowmetercatcher.count, 0)) AS T1SUM
           FROM monitor.statcatcher
           LEFT JOIN monitor.flowmetercatcher ON monitor.statcatcher.pid = monitor.flowmetercatcher.pid AND DATE(monitor.statcatcher.moment) =
     DATE(monitor.flowmetercatcher.moment)
           WHERE DATE(monitor.statcatcher.moment) = CURRENT_DATE AND message IS NOT NULL 
           GROUP BY monitor.statcatcher.job,monitor.statcatcher.pid, monitor.statcatcher.message, monitor.statcatcher.duration)AS T1
         INNER JOIN(SELECT monitor.statcatcher.job,MAX(monitor.statcatcher.moment) AS T2MAX,
     monitor.statcatcher.pid
         FROM monitor.statcatcher
         WHERE DATE(monitor.statcatcher.moment) = CURRENT_DATE
         GROUP BY monitor.statcatcher.job) AS T2
         ON T1.job = T2.job AND T1.pid = T2.pid
```